# convert array by split to integer

Tags: java, android

I get error :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt

for this block :

```
int f = Integer.parseInt(c[1]); 
limitter.setProgress(f); 
limit.setText(f + " A");
```

MAIN CODE:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");

readBufferPosition = 0;

handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        String[] c = data.split("limit");
        int x = c.length;

        if(x>1){

            int f = Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            limitter.setProgress(f);
            limit.setText(f + " A");
        }
```

What is wrong?

Here is the stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
   at com.tos.hidro.Terminal$2$1.run(Terminal.java:207)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you debug through it to find out the value of `c[1]`? What is it? Also, what do you think `data.split("limit")` does?

Comment: Can you post the value of `data` before it gets to that loop? I think `Integer.parseInt()` is trying to convert non digits to digits, thats why its complaining

Comment: Yeap c[1] is not empty i checked it. if i use as c[1] i get some numbers but i can't convert

Comment: value of data  = limit20;

Comment: Have you tried printing c[1] before making the conversion to int?

Comment: So if you do `"limit20;".split("limit")` your gonna get "20;" then do a `Integer.parseInt(c[1].replace(";",""));`

Comment: sorry about my answer. it's wrong "limit20;" it's "limit20". Yes i tried print c[1] before the conversation and i get as a string "20"

Comment: If the value is indeed "20", the error isn't comin from parseInt. Please share your actual stack trace

Comment: You can try adding `trim()` to remove any unintended whitespace. `int f = Integer.parseInt(c[1].trim());` Documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29

Comment: yeap trim() is work. Thank you